# Rails - how do you "show" a page if you don't know the id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a very simple vocabulary webapp that shows a bunch of words with their definitions on the front (index) page. Each word has a field called "knowledge," the value of which can either be "learning" or "learned."

I would like to put a link at the bottom of the index page called "Practice." Clicking on the link will take you to a page showing the word and definition of the first word in the knowledge: "learning" column. Then there will be a "next" link that takes you to the next word in the knowledge: "learning" column. When you run out of words in the knowledge: "learning" column, you're taken back to the index page.

I am getting an id => nil error. The problem appears to be that clicking on the practice link sends me to a show page which requires an id, however I do not actually query the database to determine the id of the first word until I reach the show action in the controller. How do I make a link to "show" the first word in a column?

The "practice" link on the index page looks like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Practice', page_path(@page) %>
```

I am using `resources :pages` in the routes file. 
My the show action in my controller Pages looks like this:

```
def show
  if @page.nil?
    @page = Page.where(knowledge: 'Learning').first
  else
    @next = Page.where("id > ?", params[:id]).order(:id).first 
  end
end
```

Finally, my show page looks something like this:

```
<% if @page%>
 <p> <%= @page.word %></p>
 <p>  <%= @page.content %></p>
 <p><%= link_to "Next", page_path(@next) %></p>


<% elsif @next %>
 <p> <%= @next.word %></p>
 <p>  <%= @next.content %></p>
 <p><%= link_to "Next", page_path(@next) %></p>

 <% else %>

 <p> Good Job!</p>
 <p><%= link_to "Home", pages_path %> </p>
<%end%>
```

Error message is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id].
```

The error highlights this line from my index template:

```
   <%= link_to 'Practice', page_path(@page) %>
```

*Note that I am very new to programming and rails in general. This is probably really simple.

Comment: you missed an `end` in controller `def show`, it seems?

Comment: if that's not the problem, try `p @page` after `if else` block, and see your server console, you expect to have a page object, but it should be writing nothing, meaning pages table has not the result you want.

Comment: could you paste the entire error message?

Comment: @juanpastas - the "end" word wasn't the problem, just sloppy pasting. I added error message.

Comment: yep, the error seems to be what I wrote about `@page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Rails!

The page path *requires* an id.  If you go into your project folder, and type rake routes, it will show you a list of your routes, and which require ids.  Like this:

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format) users#show
```

You are going to need to get the first record and load it in your index page:

```
def index
@page = Page.where(knowledge: 'Learning').first
end
```

Then for your link on your index page:

```
<%= link_to 'Practice', page_path(@page, first: true) %>
```

first: true is a second parameter that you can check for in your show action so you can tell if the person is coming from the index page.

Then for your show action - (params always returns a string, that's why, the 'true' is in quotes for your show action)

```
def show
  if params[:first] == 'true'
    @page = Page.where(knowledge: 'Learning').first
    @next = Page.where("id > ?", @page.id).order(:id).first
  else
    @page = Page.where("id > ?", params[:id]).order(:id).first 
    @next = Page.where("id > ?", @page.id).order(:id).first 
  end
end
```

For your view:

```
<% if @page%>
 <p> <%= @page.word %></p>
 <p>  <%= @page.content %></p>
 <p><%= link_to "Next", page_path(@next) %></p>

 <% else %>

 <p> Good Job!</p>
 <p><%= link_to "Home", pages_path %> </p>
<%end%>
```

You also may want to look into the will_paginate gem for pagination: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Answer (score 2):

In general it's a bad idea to link to a "show" action without having an object to show.  This is what the "index" action is for.

Try linking to it like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Practice', pages_path %>
```

Then in your controller do this:

```
def index
  page = Page.where(knowledge: 'Learning').first
  redirect page_path(page)
end
```

That way you'll always have an ID when the show action is called.  I think you'll also want to adjust your show method to this so that `@page` and `@next` are available to your view.

```
def show
  @page = Page.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @next = Page.where("id > ?", params[:id]).order(:id).first 
end
```